# Setting today's date in XAML

Tags: xaml, date, textblock

I want to display today's date in XAML and then return that to my view model. So this shows it in XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=dd/MMM/yyyy}"/>
```

but I want to return it in ModifiedDate, so I did this

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ModifiedDate" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=dd/MMM/yyyy}"/>
```

This doesn't work. I don't want to use datepicker. I want to use Pure XAML and do not wish to go to code. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by return it in ModifiedDate? The two codeblocks are the same, only the TextBlock in the second has a name. Do you want to use a binding to a property named ModifiedDate?

Comment: Yes, I want to bind it to a property names ModifiedDate.

Comment: Why don´t you set the ModifiedDate in your ViewModel to DateTime.Now?

Comment: I wish I could, but it is a long story.

Answer (score 6):

you have to include this name space in your xaml..if you are not able to show date..

```
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and if you want something different update your question..

Comment: Yes, this is included and not the issue.

Comment: your ques. is little bit confusing ..so what i am thinking is that you want to define you time in xaml and send this time back to your viewmodel..is it right..

Comment: thr may be a workaround like you have set the date in xaml..now this textblock is available in your page.cs  and send the text message using messanger service in mvvm to your viewmodel..look you are searching for workaround but the best way for doing this..is get your system date in your viewmodel and bind that date to your xaml textblock..